# Using Spring Hibernate getHibernateTemplate().find to to select columns

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I am using

```
List<USERS> user =
    getHibernateTemplate().find("select uid, username,email from USERS");
```

to get three columns values from the users TABLE.  But I can access no individual column value  using the "user"  object because the "user" type is an object type and I can't cast it to the USERS.
Is there any ways to use the "user" object and access individual columns value?

Comment: please post the structure of user class.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you just querying selected columns - just get the whole row(s). Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fetching only few columns, the hibernate template will return a list of object arrays.

Your example should look like this,

```
List<Object[]> userDetails =
getHibernateTemplate().find("select uid, username,email from USERS");
```

And you should know the first element is a integer and second, third are string and do cast on your own. This is very error prone ofcourse.

Comment: Many thanks Kaylan, I did something similar to what you suggest and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nilesh and Sean for your suggestions. I always deal with the objects instead of  individual columns. But this specific app works with other tables from another app which is not written in Java (That is why I am using USERS table not "User", because it is already created by another app) and is not using hibernate. I created a USERS class that implements  UserDetails and has much less columns than the original app USERS table. When I get the whole object I get a formatting error that is why I tried using selected columns instead of the object.Anyhow I wrote this code and was able to get the individual columns:

```
List user= 
            getHibernateTemplate().find("select uid, username,email from USERS where uid<>0 AND obj_type=1");


        List<USERS> l = new ArrayList<USERS>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) {
            USERS du = new USERS(); 
            Object[] obj = (Object[]) user.get(i);

            Integer uid = (Integer) obj[0];
            du.setUid(uid);
            String username = (String) obj[1];
            du.setUsername(username); 
            String email = (String) obj[2];
            du.setEmail(email); 
            l.add(du);
        }
```

My last question: isn't it more expensive to get the whole columns(the object) than getting the individuals ones?

Comment: Just in the network bandwidth you chew up. Usually, it's not an issue, but you need to be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind it that...

`getHibernateTemplate.find()` method returns List of based on passed object.

Then after this you have to take List of Users then you have to separate all resulting object and after specified a object you can access attribute of it.

Its very easy..

If you have any query then tell me

I will try my best.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public Object findByNo(Object id) throws Exception {
    List list = getHibernateTemplate().find(
            "select book from Book book " +
                    "where book.id=?",id);
    if (list.size() != 0) {
        return list.get(0);
    } else {
        return new Book();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your db table is called `USERS` and the entity class is called `User`. If that is the case, then you should do something like this:

```
List<User> users  = getHibernateTemplate().find("from User");
for(User user: users){
    // you probably don't need the id, so I'll skip that
    String email = user.getEmail();
    String userName = user.getUserName();
    // now do something with username and email address
}
```

If you use an ORM framework, deal with objects, not with Database Columns!

And about naming:

Java naming conventions suggest that a class name is in `TitleCase` (or more precisely `UpperCamelCase`), not `UPPERCASE`. Also, a  class that represents a single user should be called `User`, not `Users`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
for (TemplateAttributes templateAttributes1 : templateAttributes) {
                templateAttributes1.setTemplates(templates);
                templateAttributes1.setCreateDate(new Date());
                templateAttributes1.setCreateUser(ApplicationConstants.userName);
                templateAttributes1.setLastModified(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
                templateAttributesNew.add(templateAttributes1);
            }
            templates.setTemplateAttributes(templateAttributesNew);
            templates.setUpdateDate(new Date());
            templates.setUpdateUser(ApplicationConstants.userName);
            templates.setLastModified(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate("delete from TemplateAttributes where templateAttributePK.templates.id="+templates.getId());
            getHibernateTemplate().update(templates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<USERS> user =(List&lt;USERS>)(List&lt;?>)
    getHibernateTemplate().find("select uid, username,email from USERS");
```